# ContentProvider returning null as result in other app

Tags: java, android

I am experimenting with content provider in android and trying to get the data from other app. Here is the code

```
  public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.my.content.provider";
    public static final Uri CONTENT = Uri.parse("content://"+AUTHORITY+"/emp");
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void doLoad(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"works",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Cursor cr = getContentResolver().query(CONTENT,null,null,null,"_id");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while(cr.moveToNext())
        {
            String s1 = cr.getString(1);
            String s2 = cr.getString(2);
            sb.append(s1+"    "+s2+ "\n");
        }
        Toast.makeText(this,sb.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

And this is provider in manifest

```
 <provider
        android:name=".MyProvider"
        android:authorities="com.my.content.provider"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
    </provider>
```

now the doLoad function is working fine in the contentProvider orignal app. but when i use same doLoad in another app the Cursor object is null. My content URI is correct.

Note: I havent set any permission in any of them since i want any app to use this content provider.

Comment: I have now even set permission in provider and used that permission in user but the Cursor is till empty.

Comment: post relevant provider declaration (manifest) which is the most likely issue

Comment: i have posted the manifest of provider